# odd python error related to seaborn 'AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel''

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to pretty up some plots in matplotlib. 
On import of seaborn we are getting this error:

```
import seaborn as sns

--> 407     def UnicodeReader(f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
    408         # ignore encoding
    409         return csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
```

Has anyone else had this issue? Any thoughts on a fix?

Comment: Did you name a file `csv.py`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a possible cause of this error is a file named `csv.py`.